# Method "onBackPressed" not working on WebView Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview

I'm finishing my WebViev app but I have an issue with going back in a page using WebView, when pressing "back" button the app closes. I need to go back to a previous page on the WebView, but I get the "cannot resolve mehtod onBackPressed();" error.

Fragment Code:

```
package com.lfcchile;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class MyFragment4 extends Fragment {
private WebView webView;
public MyFragment4() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View mainView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_fragment1, container, false);
    //webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    //webView.setInitialScale(50);
    //webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    WebView webView = (WebView)mainView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new MantenerDominioWeb());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.canGoBack();
    webView.goBack();
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.lfcchile.com/sitios-interes/");
    return mainView;
}

@Override

public View onBackPressed() {
    if(webView.canGoBack()) {
        webView.goBack();
    }

    else {
       super.onBackPressed();
    }
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}


@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
}

}
```

When I put the onBackPressed on MainActivity and press the back button, the app crashes... any ideas please?

Comment: Why did u use super.onBackPressesd in else condition...You should remove the else condition and make the code super.onBackPressed with out in any condition

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using fragment, you have to get the back key touched event... Follow the below code as a reference...

```
mainView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == android.view.KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            if ((keyCode == android.view.KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
                if(webView!=null)
                {
                  if(webView.canGoBack())
                  {
                    webView.goBack();
                  }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

To get the touched key event you have to override the onkeylistener...

Comment: This worked for me on the seemingly borken Kitkat v30 webview in a fragment which would not consume the back press before. 
One comment/improvement though: onKey should return true only if the event was consumed, otherwise false.

Answer (score 2):

Fragments do not have backPressed. You have to use backPressed of its container activity. In your activity override onBackPressed & call it from fragment using getActivity.onBackPressed().

Answer (score 2):

Override onKeyDown instead of onBackPressed. Not necessarily . But this works for me

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK: 

            // back button is pressed.. Do your stuff here
            if(webView!=null)
            {
              if(webView.canGoBack())
              {
                webView.goBack();
              }
            }

            return true;
}
        return false;
}
```

Comment: logcat shows this with your code: 08-10 19:45:50.236  18458-18458/com.lfcchile W/UnimplementedWebViewApi﹕ Unimplemented WebView method onKeyDown called from: android.webkit.WebView.onKeyDown(WebView.java:2211)